# How to make slider show 4 recent news and news start from begining not from 4th

Tags: recent-posts

I am kinda new to wordpress and I wanted to know how to make my wordpress site to show recent 4 news in this slider and again all news below:

```
    class s_naujienos extends WP_Widget {

    function s_naujienos() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 's_naujienos', 'description' => 'Naujienų slideris');
        $this->WP_Widget('s_naujienos', 'Naujienų slideris', $widget_ops);
    }

    function form($instance) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, array('title' => ''));
        $title = $instance['title'];
        ?><p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" /></label></p><?php
            }

            function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
                $instance = $old_instance;
                $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
                return $instance;
            }

            function widget($args, $instance) {
                extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
                echo $before_widget;
                $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
                if (!empty($title)) {
                    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
                }
                if (have_posts()) {
                    //$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
                    //$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
                    $naujienu_sk = 4;
                    ?>
            <script>
                var newsslider = new pro3bSlider('#snauj', 500, <?php echo $naujienu_sk; ?>, true, 5000, false);
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">
                .snauj_left { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; z-index: 2; margin-left: 15px; opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40); }
                .snauj_left:hover { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; z-index: 2; margin-left: 15px; opacity:1.0; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }           
                .snauj_right { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; z-index: 2; margin-right: 15px; right: 0; opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40); }          
                .snauj_right:hover { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; z-index: 2; margin-right: 15px; right: 0; opacity:1.0; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }   
                .snauj_title { text-align: center; opacity:0.8; filter:alpha(opacity=80); font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; background: #000; font-family: MyriadPro-Regular,'Myriad Pro Regular',MyriadPro,'Myriad Pro'; position:absolute; z-index:2; bottom:0; right:0; width: 500px; height: 40px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000; }
            </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/foundation.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
            <div class="large-8 small-16 collumns" style='min-width: 500px; min-height: 282px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; border-right: 1px solid #DDDCDC;'>
                <img onclick='newsslider.left()' class='snauj_left' src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/nauj_left.png'/>
                <img onclick='newsslider.right()' class='snauj_right' src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/nauj_right.png'/>            
                <div style='width: <?php echo $naujienu_sk * 500; ?>px; height: 282px;'>
                    <?php
                    $counter = 0;
                    $argum = array('numberposts' => $naujienu_sk);
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($argum);
                    foreach ($recent_posts as $recent) {
                        the_post();
                        $counter++;
                        ?>
                        <div id='snauj<?php echo $counter; ?>' style='width: 500px; height: 282px; display: inline-block; position: relative; color: #fff; float: left; background: #000;'>
                            <div class='snauj_title'><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php
//add_image_size('my_image_media', 600, 338);
//add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300, 9999 );
//set_post_thumbnail_size( 500, 282 );

                                the_post_thumbnail('large', array('class' => 'wp-caption')); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array the_post_thumbnail('newsslider-size');  
                                ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?></div></div><?php
        }

//echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); 

        echo $after_widget;
    }

}

add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("s_naujienos");'));
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an implementation of showing all news again. Do you intend to do this inside the widget?

Comment: @ialocin The news are being showed on main website under the widget, so it is probably that widget takes 4 recent news and web page continues with rest of them, but I want him to restart from 1st new post. You can check site [link](http://fksuduva.lt). Pictures slider is 4 news and below is rest news "Naujienos

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you are just missing a [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) call after you foreach loop. Take a look at [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts), which is used by [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts), to see an example usage.

Besides that you do not need the `if (have_posts())` and `the_post();` in your widget code. But should make use of [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata).

---

**Edit:**

Example:

```
$argum = array( 
    'numberposts' => $naujienu_sk
);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $argum );
foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    // code
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Can you write the code how it should look like because when I put wp_reset_postdata() it does not work...

Comment: @user51905 I added an example to the answer. For the future, »it does not work« isn't a decent description I - or anyone - can work with.

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was not `wp_reset_postdata()`, but `rewind_posts();`, it totaly worked.